# How to visualise a teams roadmap when using Kanban

Tags: kanban, agile-coach

My team is experimenting with Kanban, which they enjoy and see the benefits.

The one sticking point that we are having is the team feels they don't have a clear view or grasp about when a particular feature will be done or when it needs to be done because of the continual stream of tickets in the todo column.

They have PI Objectives, and they know we are aiming to meet them after x number of weeks, but the granularity under that is less clear.

With Scrum, they somewhat knew that everything in the todo column must be done by the end of the sprint, but with Kanban, we don't have this, so we don't have a clear view of the road ahead.

What could we do to solve this?

I was thinking of creating a board that shows the epic level status and has a label on each card on the kanban story Jira board that shows the deadline (if any).

Comment: If you are using Kanban, are you monitoring throughput, cycle time and work item aging? With these metrics, you should be able to determine when an arbitrary work item will be complete, based on where it is in the backlog or workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you group your user stories into Epics? Some tools like Azure Devops have tools that show the progress of an epic based on the amount of US completed.